# How to IMPORTXML into Google Sheets from site with next-click/load-more pagination

Tags: arrays, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to scrape a list of news stories for each story's topic, author, timestamp and headline. The site lists the 10 most recently published stories on a URL that ends in /all-stories, with the next 10 stories on /all-stories/page/2, the next 10 on /all-stories/page/3, and so on.

I have 3 IMPORTXML formulas that are capturing the data I need on the first page:

```
=importxml("https://www.example.org/all-stories", "//div[@class='post-item-river__content___2Ae_0']/a")

=IMPORTXML("https://www.example.org/all-stories","//li[@class='post-item-river__wrapper___2c_E- with-image']/div/div")

=IMPORTXML("https://www.example.org/all-stories","//li[@class='post-item-river__wrapper___2c_E- with-image']/div/h3")
```

How do I replicate this on page/2, page/3 and so on?

I haven't seen any way to do this in Google Sheets -- [this kinda-similar story](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115556/sheets-table-from-url-with-pagination) attempt involved adding &=ROW() to the URL in the formula. But when I tried that, Sheets interpreted it as part of the URL and rightly returned nothing.

Comment: this completely depends on the URL. share a copy of your sheet with specific URL you trying to scrape

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eEA_5T7lshuIgQLwadF37xw6vo86WWpkeJlGPxcwPKw/edit?usp=sharing

Target scrape URL: www.sciencenews.org/all-stories

Answer (score 0):

try a simple array like:

```
={IMPORTXML("https://www.sciencenews.org/all-stories", "//div[@class='post-item-river__content___2Ae_0']");
  IMPORTXML("https://www.sciencenews.org/all-stories/page/2", "//div[@class='post-item-river__content___2Ae_0']");
  IMPORTXML("https://www.sciencenews.org/all-stories/page/3", "//div[@class='post-item-river__content___2Ae_0']")}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to automate capturing that data on multiple pages without inserting  a new IMPORTXML block for every row? I'm looking to capture 3 months' worth of entries — and the timestamp field and By [author name] fields are being merged together.

Comment: @ProjectFreQ as of what I am aware of, this is the only option